# rspec cannot find factory that is created in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, spree

I have a `Factory` that creates a mock `order`. It has a `before_create` in the factory to create 3 models that are necessary for `after_create` callbacks when creating an `order`. The following factory code looks like this (I realize this is a little bit messy, but its what I have currently to try to get around my problem):

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :order, :class => Spree::Order do
    # associations:
    association(:user, :factory => :user)
    association(:bill_address, :factory => :address)
    association(:ship_address, :factory => :address)
    completed_at nil
    bill_address_id nil
    ship_address_id nil
    email 'foo@example.com'

    before(:create) do |order|
      country = Spree::Country.find_by_id(214).blank? ? create(:country, :id => 214) : Spree::Country.find_by_id(214)
      state = create(:state, :country => country, :country_id => country.id)
      country.states = [state]
      FactoryGirl.create(:address, :id => 1072978592,:state => state, :country => country) if Spree::Address.find_by_id(1072978592).blank?
    end
  end
    end
```

However, when i run my tests, i keep getting errors like this:

```
  1) Spree::Calculator::DefaultTax#compute when given an order when no line items match the tax category should be 0
 Failure/Error: let!(:order) { create(:order) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Country can't be blank
 # ./spec/models/calculator/default_tax_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It's giving a validation error that the country can't be blank. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am assigning the country properly in the address and state.

```
rspec  2.13.0,
factory_girl_rails 4.2.1 (factory _girl 4.2.0),
ruby 1.9.3,
rails 3.2.13
spree 1.2.4
```

Comment: `let(:order) { Spree::Order.create }` is lazily loaded, just to make sure this is not the problem, try let bang, `let!(:order) { Spree::Order.create }. Also, if this doesn't work can you post the whole spec file and the address factory

Comment: I tried adding the exclamation point in there and it didnt do anything.

Comment: yeah sorry I couldn't help. You can use rails console in test environment to go through and play with the associations manually. Maybe you can find what is wrong that way. `rails console test`

Answer (score 0):

Your callback may not be running due to an update in the syntax of FactoryGirl.
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/23039827914/get-your-callbacks-on-with-factory-girl-3-3

Try:

```
after(:create)
```

instead of:

```
after_create
```

You can also try downgrading your version of FactoryGirl to something before 3.3.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are right that the syntax was incorrect, but that didn't fix the error from happening. I have done some updates since and I am currently getting a different error now. I have updated the original question to reflect my current error.